# Why Docker does not sync files with host when working on Raspbian

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I have simple app which is writing some logs to a folder. I'd like to have it running 24/7 so decided to go with RaspberryPi (3rd version). The app is deployed as a docker container. The issue I'm having is that files with logs are not appearing on host - meaning on my Pi device despite of volume configuration in docker-compose. When I run it on my Windows machine in Docker everything works as expected.

My docker file:

```
ARG RUNTIME_IMAGE_VERSION
ARG SDK_IMAGE_VERSION

FROM $RUNTIME_IMAGE_VERSION AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM $SDK_IMAGE_VERSION AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Pinger/Pinger.csproj", "Pinger/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Pinger/Pinger.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Pinger"
RUN dotnet build "Pinger.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Pinger.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Pinger.dll"]
```

Docker-compose for running it on Windows (this works perfectly):

```
version: '3.7'

services: 
  pinger:
    image: pinger
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Pinger/Dockerfile
      args:
        - RUNTIME_IMAGE_VERSION=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:3.1
        - SDK_IMAGE_VERSION=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1
    volumes:
      - c:/temp/logs:/var/lib/docker
```

and for Pi:

```
version: '3.7'

services: 
  pingerpi:
    image: pingerpi
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Pinger/Dockerfile
      args:
        - RUNTIME_IMAGE_VERSION=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:3.1-bullseye-slim-arm32v7
        - SDK_IMAGE_VERSION=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1-bullseye
    volumes:
      - /tmp:/var/lib/docker
```

Burnt Raspbian image to SD card using Raspberry Pi Imager, assuming Raspbian version is most recent one.

I can see the log files in var/lib/docker folder, I guess it could be an access rights issue but neither during build and runtime this is manifested somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Gosh, silly me :) calling inspect for mounts returned non of them, I just realized that volumes are being setup only on docker-compose up, not on docker run. Couple of afternoons wasted.